# Use redis pub/sub to connect Tornado processes

Tags: redis, tornado, publish-subscribe, interprocess

I have two Tornado processes `X` and `Y`. A handler in `X` handles post requests, and when such a request arrives, in addition to making changes in `X`, I also want to alter some variables stored in `Y`.

I would like to use `Redis`'s PUB/SUB to do this. It is obvious that, in the handler of `X`, I need to publish a message to the channel which is subscribed by 'Y'.

This subscription in `Y` should be long-running, so that whenever a message is published to the channel, something in `Y` should automatically update the variables in memory. However, it is not clear to me how to implement this subscription and the resulting updating in `Y`, as it can't be a normal handler. I plan to the asynchronous redis client `tornado-redis` for this, if that makes any difference.

Some example would be great help!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Redis PUB/SUB solution but, alternatives. If you have Redis on your stack already, you might as well use that (or better yet a message queue).

1. Easiest is to have a `tornado.web.RequestHandler` for this in Y. When X needs to make the change, have X send an HTTPRequest to Y. Payload can be JSON, form-encoded, binary.
2. Create a socket within Y, bind it and add `IOLoop.add_handler` listening on that socket with a `callback` to run. When X needs to make the change, have it connect to that socket. (Payload can be JSON, binary). This would require a little socket accepting & reading if you need to send a message across.

Needless to say, both should be behind firewalls.